# Scraping amazon product with Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I try scraping amazon products with using Python but output is

```py
image element not found
title element not found.
price element not found.
dimensions element not found.
sold_by element not found.
Item 1 is None.
Item 2 is None.
Item 3 is None.
Item 4 is None.
Item 5 is None.
Saved to urunler.pptx
```

Here is my code;

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

# SCRAPİNG WİTH URL
def get_product_info(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    # Ürün bilgileri
    image_element = soup.find("img", {"id": "landingImage"})
    if image_element is not None:
        image = image_element["src"]
    else:
        print("image element not found.")
        image = None

    title_element = soup.find("span", {"id": "productTitle"})
    if title_element is not None:
        title = title_element.string.strip()
    else:
        print("title element not found.")
        title = None

    price_element = soup.find("span", {"id": "priceblock_ourprice"})
    if price_element is not None:
        price = price_element.string
    else:
        print("price element not found.")
        price = None

    dimensions_element = soup.find("span", {"class": "a-list-item"})  # Bu, genellikle doğru olan bir tahmindir.
    if dimensions_element is not None:
        dimensions = dimensions_element.string
    else:
        print("dimensions element not found.")
        dimensions = None

    sold_by_element = soup.find("a", {"id": "sellerProfileTriggerId"})
    if sold_by_element is not None:
        sold_by = sold_by_element.string
    else:
        print("sold_by element not found.")
        sold_by = None

    # Bilgileri döndürme
    return image, title, price, dimensions, sold_by

# Saving informations to PPTX
def save_to_pptx(info, pptx_filename):
    prs = Presentation()
    slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]

    # Bilgileri slide'a ekleme
    for i, item in enumerate(info):
        if item is not None:
            slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
            left = top = Inches(i)
            txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, Inches(6), Inches(1))
            tf = txBox.text_frame
            p = tf.add_paragraph()
            p.text = str(item)
        else:
            print(f"Item {i+1} is None.")

    # Dosyayı kaydetme
    try:
        prs.save(pptx_filename)
        print(f"Saved to {pptx_filename}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to save pptx: {e}")

# Request URL
url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08NDJZ2JZ"  # Bu URL'yi istediğiniz URL ile değiştirin

# Saving Product Details PPTX
info = get_product_info(url)
save_to_pptx(info, "urunler.pptx")`
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup is web scraping, not screen scraping. You do screen scraping with computer vision software.

Comment: Selam Emre. You are propably being blocked by Amazon. Check for "api-services-support@amazon.com" string in your response, if present the string is present that means you've been blocked.